# Thinkster MEAN Stack Factory

Tags: angularjs, factory, mean.io

I was going through the Thinkster.io MEAN Stack tutorial and had a question about why my implementation doesn't work. I know this isn't what is exactly being asked but was wondering how you would make this work. I wanted to use the factory to show my posts that I moved into my factory from the controller. The code is shown below for app.js.

`

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', []);

app.factory('posts', [function(){
var o = {posts:[{title: 'post 1', upvotes: 5}, {title: 'post 2', upvotes: 2},  {title: 'post 3', upvotes: 15}, {title: 'post 4', upvotes: 9},{title: 'post 5', upvotes: 4}];
};
return o;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts',function($scope, posts){
  $scope.test = 'Hello world!';
  $scope.posts = posts.posts; 
  $scope.addPost = function(){
    if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === ''){
     return; 
    }
    $scope.posts.push({title: $scope.title, link: $scope.link, upvotes: 0}); 
    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.link = '';
    };
  $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post){
    post.upvotes += 1; 
  };

}]);
```

`

Originally the object of posts in the factory was in the controller as $scope.posts. Now it is in the factory (being referenced as posts.posts) and does not display. How would you make the array display in the html, as I have {{post.title}} under a main controller div with ng-repeat that works prior to the factory being introduced.

Comment: May be not the answer but you should keep addPost and increment Upvotes method in factory only...

Comment: the question is why can't i put my posts in a posts factory and then reference them as posts.posts

Comment: do you get console.log($scope.posts)???

Comment: Your json data is not formatted properly. You have an `;` before the data ends. Remove the `;` after the `]`

Comment: thanks ViChU! that was it! Since i'm just learning angular I didnt know if I needed to inject something else. I'm glad it was just that small issue!

Comment: If you open up your developers console with your code - it will point out that you have "app2.js:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;" - and give the line number. For next time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON data is not formatted properly. There is a semi-colon inside your JSON data after the array `posts` .

Use this and it should work:

```
var o = {
    posts: [{
        title: 'post 1',
        upvotes: 5
    }, {
        title: 'post 2',
        upvotes: 2
    }, {
        title: 'post 3',
        upvotes: 15
    }, {
        title: 'post 4',
        upvotes: 9
    }, {
        title: 'post 5',
        upvotes: 4
    }]
};
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I am glad it was just a small issue. This works!

Comment: Sure ! Have fun coding :)